# Returning XML from webmethod

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, vb.net, webmethod

I am using an ajax PageMethod to call an asp.net webmethod. From there I'm trying to pass a lot of XML back to a callback javascript function.

Currently I just convert the XML into a string and pass it in that format. But it seems that if the string is too long it causes an error.

Here's the VB:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function getXML() As String
   Dim strXML
   strXML=getLoadsOfXML().InnerXml;
   Return strXML
End Function
```

Here's the javascript:

```
function loadGrid(){
    PageMethods.getXML(myCallback);
} 

//This function doesn't get called if strXML is too long
function myCallback(strXML){
    useXML(strXML);
}
```

Here's the error:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.Net.WebServiceFailedException:
>   The server method 'getXML' failed with the following error:
>   System.InvalidOperationException-- Error during serialization or
>   deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the
>   string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.

So my question is: Is there a better way to pass the XML from VB to javascript, or a way to allow large strings to be passed without error?

Comment: What's the error? Is on the server or the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151987/unlimited-for-maxjsonlength) appears to be what you want, but according to the answer the default value is 4MB. I would look into if you *really* want to be returning so much data to the client (just imagine someone on a very slow internet connection).

Comment: For some reason the default was much lower for me. Increasing it to 4MB seemed to do the trick. Thanks!